# Отсутствие вывода программы при запуске в QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Установил `Qt`, создал простейший `C++` проект, скомпилировал, а при запуске просто открывается консоль и ничего не происходит.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А что должно происходить? Выведется "Hello World!" и консоль сразу закроется. Поставьте в конец программы (до ретурна) ввод с клавиатуры или паузу и сообщение тогда увидите. И причем тут вообще Qt? У Вас классическое c++ console приложение.

Comment: в том и соль, что консоль открывается и НЕ закрывается. Просто висит пустой. В консоли Qt статус: проект выполняется

Comment: А среда разработки какая?

Comment: ну, Qt Creator

Comment: Под виндой запускаем?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: повторил у себя - работает так как ожидалось (у меня Fedora 18). А вот под виндой помню не все так гладко было, там qtcreator перехватывал вывод.

Поищите внизу "application output" - возможно Ваш вывод там.

Comment: неа) Запускается ... и просто висит :(

Comment: @KoVadim, переместите, пожалуйста, свой комментарий в ответы, раз он помог автору.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    std::cout<<"Hello!";
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Попробуйте вместо

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

написать

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

И добавьте в файле проекта

```
CONFIG += console
```

Должно помочь.

Comment: к сожалению, не помогло.
CONFIG += console Был изначально